'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
Yesterday I installed Python and added it to PATH. Then I created a virtual environment using virtualenv.
I then activated the environment and pip-installed django (using pip install django) and started a project by django-admin startproject project_name.
Then I moved the virtual environment folder inside the project directory (formerly it was its sibling dirctory).
I worked with the project and everything was fine until today when I opened it again. python manage.py runserver still does good but when I use django-admin commands it gives the error in the question title. It's not recognized but yesterday it was when I started the project (I did activate the environment again).
The only difference from yesterday is that I upgraded pip.
I looked up stackoverflow and it had plenty of questions for my problem but most of them had problem with PATH (which I had configured correctly and didn't have a problem with) or they had used django instead of django-admin or they were on Linux and had problems with sudo (but I'm on Windows 10).
What can I do to solve this?

Did you activate the virtual environment again?

@willeM_VanOnsem Yes yes ofcourse, let me mention it in the question

Although perhaps not really the answer you are looking for django-admin is just a shortcut of python -m django, so you can use python -m django startapp foo instead of django-admin startapp foo.

Never worked with django, but where is this django-admin command supposed to be? If it can't be found on your hard disk, you can't execute it. Are you sure that on Windows, a BAT, CMD or EXE file of this name is included in the Django installation? In addition, you didn't say which shell you are using (Windows command shell, or Powershell). Perhaps the missing command is supposed to be a cmdlet for Powershell?

@willeM_VanOnsem python -m django does not work either and shows the same error saying 'error: no module named django'. It's like I've never installed django while it is indeed installed. I just made an experiment, when I move the virtual environment folder back to where it was, django module is found thus no error is thrown but when I move it again where I want it to be, the problems arise.

@MahdiShirazi: well you did activate an environment with django installed? What if you install django in that environment again (for example with pip).

@user1934428 It resides in virtual-environmet-folder-name\Scripts\django-admin.exe and is now before my eyes, so I assure you, yes it does exist. The problem is when the  virtual-environmet-folder is moved this command is not found but where I move it back to its original location, it is found and the problem goes away.

The virtual environment usually has some file paths hardcoded in its scripts, when you activate it it uses these and updates the PATH environment variable. There's no documented way to update these paths and its best to simply recreate the venv as mentioned in the duplicates.

Since you know, where the EXE exists: Did you try to run django-admin by providing the full path to it?

This error usually occurs when you activate your virtual environment in another folder where you created it. Since you said you moved the virtual environment, I would recommend moving it back, closing the project and trying again. I assume that Python saves the original path of the virtual environment somewhere in the cache and is therefore looking in the wrong directory.

Yes, I moved the folder back to where it was and everything got alright. But the problem is that I want it to be at the new location. Is there a way I can tell Python about the new path?

@MahdiShirazi: just create a new environment.
